# Group by with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have to display some data in php the structure of data is like this

```
id  channel_id  added_by

1     1          9999
2     1          195
3     8          9999
4     1          180
5     1          195
6     8          9999
7     1          9999
8     1          195
9     8          9999
```

I need to show total count of channel id = 1 only like this

```
channel_id   total  added_by

1            2           9999
1            4          -1
```

Its like count of all channel id which are added by 9999 and all other added are assumed as (-1)

I am able to do it like

```
SELECT channel_id, added_by, sum(id) as total 
from table 
where channel_id = 1 
group by channel_id  ,added_by;
```

but it gives following result which is not as I need

```
channel_id  added_by total 
1            9999      2
1             195      3
1             180      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`CASE..WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expressions, you can determine a "modified" `added_by` value, and `GROUP BY` on the modified value instead.

Also, `SUM(id)` will not give you correct count of rows. It would rather add up the `id` values. You can use [`COUNT(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) instead to count the number of rows:

```
SELECT channel_id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN added_by <> 9999 THEN -1 
         ELSE 9999 
       END AS modified_added_by, 
       COUNT(*) as total 
FROM your_table_name 
WHERE channel_id = 1 
GROUP BY channel_id, modified_added_by
```

**Result**

```
| channel_id | modified_added_by | total |
| ---------- | ----------------- | ----- |
| 1          | -1                | 4     |
| 1          | 9999              | 2     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYFL11Q9n5DdbLSNeV3wBg/0)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

`SELECT count(*) as total, channel_id, added_by  from table group by channel_id, added_by;`

Comment: How it will generate -1 in added_by column.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/437406/2

```
SELECT channel_id,
       IF(added_by=9999,9999,-1) new_col,
       COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY channel_id, new_col
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT channel_id,
if(9999,9999,-1) as added_by,
sum(id) as total
from table
where channel_id = 1
group by channel_id,added_by;
```